# Python Calling methods across classes in seperate files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a python tkinter application that is separated in multiple files. Two files hold classes and both get imported to the `parent` file where one instance of each is created. However, I need a method of one class to call a method of the other class. How would I do this without creating instances in the child files  and importing those? Since each class will be a tkinter Frame and needs a parent I cannot instantiate the child classes inside their respective files.

This is a simple version of what I am trying to do:

parent file: `Master.py`

```
import Child1
import Child2

child1 = Child1()
child2 = Child2()
```

Child 1 file: `Child1.py`

```
class Child1():
    def __init__(self):
        text1 = 'I am Child 1'

    def get_called(self):
        print(text1)
```

Child 2 file: `Child2.py`

```
class Child2():
    def __init__(self):
        text2 = 'I am Child 2'

    def call_child1(self):
        # need to call get_called method of Child1 here
```

In the final version `call_child1` would be called through a tkinter button and run a bunch of other code as well as calling a method of child1.

I am running Python 3.8.1 one windows 10.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `child1` instance as argument in your `child2` instance :

```
# parent file: Master.py

import Child1
import Child2

child1 = Child1()
child2 = Child2(child1)

# Child 1 file: Child1.py

class Child1():
    def __init__(self):
        text1 = 'I am Child 1'

    def get_called(self):
        print(text1)

# Child 2 file: Child2.py

class Child2():
    def __init__(self, ch1):
        text2 = 'I am Child 2'
        self.child1 = ch1

    def call_child1(self):
        self.child1.get_called()
        # need to call get_called method of Child1 here
```

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly. I will try to make this work on the larger scale.